# Check value of post meta within IF statement

Tags: loop, post-meta

I am creating a function to update the post excerpt using the value of the custom field 'post_preview'. During the loop, a new post_meta is being created and set to true, so I know the conversion has completed already.

**Question**
How would I check if the post_meta ('preview_text_conversion') is **FALSE** during my IF statement?

```
$posts = get_posts();
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

  $post_id = ( $post->ID ); // Current post ID
  $post_excerpt = get_field( 'preview_text', $post_id ); // ACF field

  if (($post_excerpt) && !empty($post_excerpt)) {

     $post_array = array(

         'ID'            => $post_id,
         'post_excerpt'  => $post_excerpt

     );

     wp_update_post( $post_array );

     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'preview_text_conversion', true );

  }
}
```

**My attempt:**

```
$meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'preview_text_conversion', true );

if (($post_excerpt) && !empty($post_excerpt) && !isset($meta_value) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'preview_text_conversion', true );
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Your attempt looks OK.

Comment: The attempt is missing a closing bracket `)`, the issue is broken PHP syntax

Comment: Use `empty()` instead of `isset()` when you try to check if your meta values exist. In your case you can also use `strlen` because you ask for a single.